# Use CCTray 1.2 to connect to ccnet 1.0

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Is it possible to use CCTray 1.2 to access older Cruise Control .Net 1.0? I was thinking it should be possible to use the "Supply custom HTTP URL" option, but I don't know how to configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think it is possible as 1.3 and 1.4 intermingled quite nice. I think the URL form you are looking for is http://yourwebhost/ccnet at least that is what works in 1.3 and 1.4 I will point out 1.4.3 should be out soon, and with all of the bug fixes and added functionality 1.4.3 would be a good upgrade target if you are thinking of going that way, then you could get everything back on the same version.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with 1.0, and sadly this instance is the one I don't have control over :(. Anyway, thanks for help